# How to change the encoding of notepad via Qt

Tags: qt

I'm opening a file in notepad via Qt but notepad reads it in wrong encoding. I'll let pictures explain... (I circled the encoding in both pictures)

[image]

That's what I'm getting

And that's what I want to get

[image]

How to force notepad read it in correct encoding?

Comment: But this is two different files... encoding is not the main problem here

Comment: the second file is the same as the first but opened using a program which will open it as a temporary file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modify your file before opening in notepad - add UTF-8 marker according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

Here is code (simplified, works in Windows):

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    const QString notepath = "D:\\your-file.bin";
    const static uint8_t utf8marker[] = {0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF};

    QFile file(notepath);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    auto buffer = file.readAll();

    buffer.prepend(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(utf8marker), sizeof(utf8marker));

    file.seek(0);
    file.write(buffer);
    file.close();

    QProcess::startDetached("C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", {notepath});
    return 0;
}
```